# Change a jquery ajax POST request into a fetch api POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I have some json data that I have been posting to an API using $.ajax but I would like to update this to use the fetch API. However I seem to have it setup the Fetch API request ends up returning a 403 so I must be missing something but I can't work it out.

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            'title': data.title,
            'body': data.body,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token,
            'request_json': true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

Fetch attempt (one of many):

```
let payload = {
    'title': data.title,
    'body': data.body,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token,
    'request_json': true
}

let request = new Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body:  JSON.stringify( payload )
});

fetch(request)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
```

I have tried with various different headers, content encoding and sending the data as form data using:

```
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

let request = new Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body:  form_data
});
...
```

Any help would be great and if you need any more info let me know

Thanks

Comment: Why not  headers: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. I will give it a go again, perhaps something else was messing it up!

Comment: @sideshowbarker — The working (jQuery) code uses www form encoding. There's nothing to suggest the server supports a JSON formatted request.

Answer (score 3):

To port an existing `jQuery.ajax` request to fetch, you need to consider that jQuery always includes cookies for you, but `fetch` does not.

[Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (emphasis mine):

> Note that the fetch specification differs from jQuery.ajax() in mainly two ways that bear keeping in mind:
>   - The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status [ ... ]
>   - By default, **fetch won't send or receive any cookies** from the server, **resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials header must be sent)**.

---

Edit: spec has changed since then, so this should no longer be a problem:

> Since Aug 25, 2017. **The spec changed the default credentials policy to same-origin. Firefox changed since 61.0b13**.

So the following (returning to original answer) only applies to "older" browsers.

Thanks David Richmond from comments :)

---

So you get [403 (Forbidden)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) because your API likely relies on cookies for authentication/authorization (even in your case, where you send a `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, the server-side framework might still expect a cookie with that -- guessing Django?).

To fix this, [add `credentials: "same-origin"` to your `Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) (*), like so:

```
let request = new Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
});
```

(*) Valid options for `credentials` are:

- `omit`: Never send cookies. This is the default (and your problem).
- `same-origin`: Only send cookies if the URL is on the same origin as the calling script.
- `include`: Always send cookies, even for cross-origin calls.

Comment: Note: spec changed in 2017, modern browsers now default to `same-origin`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Thanks David, amended the answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> ```
> 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
> ```

and

> ```
>  body:  JSON.stringify( payload )
> ```

JSON Encoding is not the same thing as WWW Form Encoding!

---

You also tried

> ```
> form_data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );
> ```

FormData objects are converted to Multipart MIME.

Multipart MIME is also not the same as WWW Form Encoded data.

JSON nested inside Multipart MIME even less so.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909620/convert-json-into-uri-encoded-string) describes how to convert an object (`payload`) into a Form Encoded string.