# Fetch API for Django POST requests

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, fetch-api

I'm trying to remove jQuery from a React/Redux/Django webapp and replace the `$.ajax` method with the Fetch API. I've more or less got all my GET requests working fine and I seem to be able to hit my POST requests, but I cannot seem to format my request in such a way as to actually get my POST data into the Django `request.POST` object. Every time I hit my /sign_in view, the `request.POST` object is empty. My entire app's backend is built around using Django forms (no Django templates, just React controlled components) and I would really like to not have to rewrite all my views to use `request.body` or `request.data`.

Here is all the code I can think that would be relevant, please let me know if there's more that would be helpful:

**This is the curried function I use to build my full POST data and attach the CSRF token:**

```
const setUpCsrfToken = () => {
  const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')

  return function post (url, options) {
  const defaults = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'credentials': 'include',
    'headers': {
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }

  const merged = merge(options, defaults)
  return fetch(url, merged)
  }
}

export const post = setUpCsrfToken()
```

**This is the API method I use from my React app:**

```
export const signIn = data => {
  return post('/api/account/sign_in/', data)
}
```

**The data when it is originally packaged up in the React app itself is as simple as an object with string values:**

```
{
    email: 'email@email.com',
    password: 'password
}
```

I've looked at these questions and found them to be nominally helpful, but I can't figure out to synthesize an answer for myself that takes into account what I assume is some of the intricacies of Django:

- [POST Request with Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565706/post-request-with-fetch-api)
- [Change a jquery ajax POST request into a fetch api POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429145/change-a-jquery-ajax-post-request-into-a-fetch-api-post)
- [Convert JavaScript object into URI-encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909620/convert-json-into-uri-encoded-string)
- [Is there a better way to convert a JSON packet into a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848340/is-there-a-better-way-to-convert-a-json-packet-into-a-query-string)

Thanks!

Comment: Facing same situation, Is there any solution?. Any better way to skip the changes in views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the appropriate `X-Requested-With` header. jQuery does this [under the hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L59).

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

So, in your example, you would want something like:

```
const setUpCsrfToken = () => {
  const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')

  return function post (url, options) {
    const defaults = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'credentials': 'include',
      'headers': new Headers({
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      })
    }

    const merged = merge(options, defaults)
    return fetch(url, merged)
  }
}
```