# ReactJS Fetch drop-in replacement for this AJAX boilerplate

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, http-post, fetch-api

Background:

The following `AJAX` code works successfully (`ReactJS + JQuery frontend, PHP backend`).

```
    const data = {request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/site/server.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json", 
        success: (JSobject) => {
            this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
        }
    });
```

In Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up as "`Form Data`" like so:

[image]

At the PHP server backend, there's this line of code:

```
    $request_type = $_POST["request_type"];
```

---

In an attempt to learn how to do Fetch (I've avoided it so far mostly because I had AJAX boilerplate that worked well), I've been playing around with trying to build a drop-in replacement for the above code.

I tried this:

```
    const data = {request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50};

    fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
        .then((JSobject) => {
            this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
        });
```

But I get this PHP error:

> Notice: Undefined index: request_type in .....server.php

And in Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up like so:

[image]

---

So, I tried changing the data to JSON.stringify(data) like so:

```
    const data = {request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50};

    fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then((JSobject) => {
            this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
        });
```

But I still get the exact same PHP error:

> Notice: Undefined index: request_type in .....server.php

And in Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up like so:

[image]

---

Out of general frustration (although it's pointless because I'd be still using JQuery), I thought I'd use JQuery's `$.param()`, and that would surely work.

So I tried this:

```
    const data = $.param({request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50});

    fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
        .then((JSobject) => {
            this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
        });
```

Still get the same PHP error

> Notice: Undefined index: request_type in .....server.php

And in Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up like so:

[image]

---

My question: how do I modify the `Fetch` code above so that it becomes a drop-in replacement for the `AJAX` code up top.

*I realize that the use of horizontal lines can be bothersome for some. You can give yourself permission to believe that it really helps a lot of us regular folks follow what's going on in the question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for others who might encounter this issue in future (and also for my own reference). Figured out the answer via [this link](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/) and [this link](https://codepen.io/dericksozo/post/fetch-api-json-php). The following code worked:

```
fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => {
      return response.json();
   }).then((JSobject) => {
       this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
      });
```

I had to change some PHP code on the server. The initial "gatekeeper" code was:

```
$_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);

$request_type = $_POST["request_type"];
```

This had to be commented out:

```
$_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);   //this had to be commented out
```

And this had to be added instead:

```
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$_POST = json_decode($content, true);
```

And in Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up as "`Request Payload`":

[image]

---

I also saw some suggestions to add a "`headers`" key like so:

```
fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",},
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => {
      return response.json();
   }).then((JSobject) => {
       this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
      });
```

This did also work, but in Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up as "`Form Data`":

[image]

---

Another way to do this is by wrapping the object (to be sent) in JQuery's `$.param()` (I was interested in this because I often use `$.param()` to append key-values to `form.serialize()`, on the client side before sending to the PHP on the server)

```
const data = $.param({request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50});

fetch("http://localhost/site/server.php", {
method: "POST",
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",},
body: data
}).then(response => {
   return response.json();
     }).then((JSobject) => {
      this.setState({arr: JSobject.arr});
       });
```

The advantage of doing it this way was that no changes were needed to the code on the server side.

In Chrome Dev Tools `server.php`'s Headers show up as"`Form Data`":

[image]

---

Without using JQuery:

Re: the previous method (using `$.param()`), it's possible to do it completely without `JQuery`, but then one would need some function to chain the javascript object's key-value pairs while properly encoding special characters as x-www-form-urlencoded ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792279/1883050) explains how to do it).

E.g., instead of this:

```
const data = $.param({request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50});

...
body: data
```

One would do this:

```
const data = {request_type:"load_data", start:1, end:50};

...

...
body: "request_type=load_data&start=1&end=50"
```