# how to send encoded JSON to new page and decode it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say i have a **JSON**   `{"ID":"1","Name":"XYZ"}`  I want to encode this data and send it to new page say new.html and display this data as `ID: 1 Name: XYZ`. How can I achieve this?

Till now i've tried this:

```
url = 'new.html?' + encodeURIComponent(window.btoa(JSON.stringify(str)));
document.location.href = url;
```

This code is in my first.html script tag. In my new.html I tried this:

```
<div id='here'></div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var url = document.location.href,
                    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                    data = {}, tmp;
                    console.log(JSON.parse(window.atob(params)));
                for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                    tmp = params[i].split('=');
                    data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
                }
                document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.id;
            }    
        </script>
```

But in console.log i'm getting an error: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON into uri-encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909620/convert-json-into-uri-encoded-string)

Comment: The `btoa` is pointless, but shouldn't prevent you from achieving your goal. What's the problem?

Comment: hi @Quentin, i've updated my question. please check.

Comment: If the object has only one one dimension, you could add all the params to the url as key-value pairs: url?param1=value1&param2=value2...

Comment: actually @SergioTx this data is from web service so i don't know what data will be returned from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Look at how you encoded it:

> ```
> encodeURIComponent
> ```

You have to reverse that with [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: what i did is replaced this line: `JSON.parse(window.atob(params)` with `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params)` and it gave me an error, so i removed `JSON.parse` sorry I thought data got decoded but when i saw in debug i realized it didn't. Sorry it was my mistake.