# Process inputted data for JS Fetch Api request like jQuery does in Ajax request when processData is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fetch

First of all. Code of `ajax_handler.php`

```
<?php
$res = $_POST;
$res['response'] = 'Custom';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

I have *jQuery Ajax* function with `Promise` wrapper like this.

```js
const _sendAjax = async (url, params = {}, dataType = 'json', method = 'POST') => new Promise(async (accept, reject) => {
    if (url.trim().length < 1)
        return reject('Invalid Url');
    method = method.trim().toUpperCase();
    if (!['POST', 'GET'].includes(method))
        return reject('Invalid Ajax Method');
    let u = new URL(url, window.location.href);
    u.searchParams.set('upd', Math.random() * 1000 + new Date().getMilliseconds());
    url = u.toString();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        processData: true,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: params,
        success: data => accept(data),
        error: (request, status, error) => {
            reject({ request, status, error });
        }
    });
});

// Callings
_sendAjax('ajax_handler.php', { a: 22, b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error));// {"a":"22","b":"23","response":"Custom"}

_sendAjax('ajax_handler.php', { a: [1, 2, 3, 4], b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error));// {"a":["1","2","3","4"],"b":"23","response":"Custom"}

_sendAjax('ajax_handler.php', { a: { c: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: 45 }, b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error)); // {"a":{"c":["1","2","3","4"],"d":"45"},"b":"23","response":"Custom"}
```

**Responses (Respectively)**

```js
console.log({"a":"22","b":"23","response":"Custom"});

console.log({"a":["1","2","3","4"],"b":"23","response":"Custom"});

console.log({"a":{"c":["1","2","3","4"],"d":"45"},"b":"23","response":"Custom"});
```

See, the variation in submitted data as `params`

I tried to convert this function to *JS Fetch Api*.

```js
const _sendFetch = async (url, params = {}, dataType = 'json', method = 'POST') => new Promise(async (accept, reject) => {
    if (url.trim().length < 1)
        return reject('Invalid Url');
    method = method.trim().toUpperCase();
    if (!['POST', 'GET'].includes(method))
        return reject('Invalid Ajax Method');
    let u = new URL(url, window.location.href);
    u.searchParams.set('upd', Math.random() * 1000 + new Date().getMilliseconds());
    let fetchOptions = {
        credentials: 'include',
        cache: 'no-store',
        redirect: 'follow',
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }
    if (Object.keys(params).length)
        if (method === 'POST')
            fetchOptions.body = Object.keys(params).map(x => encodeURIComponent(x) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[x])).join('&');
        else if (method === 'GET')
            Object.keys(params).forEach(x => u.searchParams.set(encodeURIComponent(x), encodeURIComponent(params[x])));
    url = u.toString();
    return fetch(url, fetchOptions)
        .then(res => (res.status === 200 && res.ok) ? res : reject(res))
        .then(res => dataType === 'json' ? accept(res.json()) : accept(res.text()))
        .catch(error => reject(error));
});

// Callings
_sendFetch('ajax_handler.php', { a: 22, b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error)); // {"a":"22","b":"23","response":"Custom"}

_sendFetch('ajax_handler.php', { a: [1, 2, 3, 4], b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error)); // {"a":"1,2,3,4","b":"23","response":"Custom"}

_sendFetch('ajax_handler.php', { a: { c: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: 45 }, b: 23 }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.error(error)); // {"a":"[object Object]","b":"23","response":"Custom"}
```

Responses (Respectively)

```js
console.log({"a":"22","b":"23","response":"Custom"});

console.log({"a":"1,2,3,4","b":"23","response":"Custom"});

console.log({"a":"[object Object]","b":"23","response":"Custom"});
```

**Problem:**

Obviously, I can't process and send inputted data as *jQuery* is doing because of `processData: true,`. *jQuery* seem to handle data efficiently for both `POST` as well as `GET`.

I can't to figure out a way to replicate working of `processData` functionality of *jQuery Ajax* as the `params` have lots of variation and I need some generic code to process inputted data for *Fetch* as *jQuery* does.

I want to do this in **JS** only without third party libraries like *jQuery*.

Comment: I don’t see why you are handling GET and POST separately here to begin with, when it comes to assembling your data - the format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the exact same for both to begin with, the only difference is that with GET, it gets added to the URL as query string, whereas with POST, it gets put into the body. You should probably not need much more than https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467386/1427878 here to prepare your data.

Comment: @CBroe. The question you mentioned, 'encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params))` and `new URLSearchParams(params)` does not work as per my need on complex data like `{ a: { c: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: 45 }, b: 23 }` and I can't get the desired result. Also, `new URLSearchParams({ a: { c: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: 45 }, b: 23 }).toString()` results in `a=%5Bobject+Object%5D&b=23`

Comment: You probably need a recursive solution here, because `[object Object]` is what you get when you force an object into string context.

Comment: Are you trying to completely get rid of jQuery here? Because if not, you could simply use its https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: @CBroe, I know about `jQuery.param`, but as you have guessed, I want to do it without *jQuery*.

Comment: https://github.com/knowledgecode/jquery-param has a light-weight implementation of that, that doesn’t need jQuery. Either embed it as-is, or extract the relevant logic from it.

Comment: @CBroe. Thanks, https://github.com/knowledgecode/jquery-param seems to work for my issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did mention that I only want the solution in **JS** but as commented by `@CBore` that I have few options in this matter.

1. Write my own recursive function.
2. Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467386/4903314). But this is not working for my scenario as the params are not just simple object.

```js
console.log(new URLSearchParams({ a: { c: [1, 2, 3, 4], d: 45 }, b: 23 }).toString());
```

3. Use [jQuery.param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). But I do not want to use a full library just for a single function / advantage.
4. Use light-weight library like [jquery-param](https://github.com/knowledgecode/jquery-param).

So in the end, I have settled for **[jquery-param](https://github.com/knowledgecode/jquery-param)** for the time being.